# Computing separatrix orbit

Tags: differential-equations, precision-and-accuracy

I would like to numerically compute the separatrix orbit for a particle in a few potential wells, given by the negative of

```
J1[delta_, w_] := (4*((delta/(w + 2^(1/6)*delta))^12
  - (delta/(w + 2^(1/6)*delta))^6) + 1) - w
```

The effect of the $\delta$ parameter is sketched in the first sketch (blue / orange / green for $\delta = 2,1,0.5$ respectively. As $\delta \to 0$ a non-smooth potential is recovered.
[image]

I am interested to numerically compute the separatrix motion (starting from the "top" of the hill close to the origin, rolling down and up to the right, turning back and asymptotically climbing to the top again) as $\delta$ approaches values as small as possible. The analytical solution in the limit $\delta \to 0$ is easy to find and equals $g(w) = -\frac{1}{2} (w^2-2)$ on the domain $ \vert x \vert \leq \sqrt{2}$, in Mathematica

```
sexact[x_] := Piecewise[{{-0.5*(x^2 - 2), x < Sqrt[2]}, {0, x > 0}}]
```

but I found the numerical process very interesting and would like to learn how is best performed to get high accuracy. I am unable to retrieve anything close to separatrix motion, just periodic.

This is how I approached it. Start with $\delta = 0.5$ and set for convenience

```
U[x_] := J1[0.5, x]
```

First I find the ordinate of the hill top

```
max = First@NMaximize[{-U[x], 0 <= x < 0.5 }, {x}, Method -> "NelderMead"]
```

after which, I find the horizontal position of the turning point on the right

```
turn = Values@Last@NSolve[{-U[x] == max, 0.5 <= x}, x, Reals, WorkingPrecision -> 40] // Normal
```

Now I can solve the motion equation, which I do in two ways for later purposes and comparison

```
stest = NDSolve[{y''[x] - U'[y[x]] == 0, y[0] == turn[[1]], y'[0] == 0}, y,
  {x, 0, L}];
s11 = NDSolveValue[{y''[x] - U'[y[x]] == 0, y[0] == turn[[1]], y'[0] == 0}, y,
  {x, 0, L}, Method -> {"BDF", "MaxDifferenceOrder" -> 1}];
```

I plot the results in the second plot (orange -> exact for the $\delta \to 0$ limit, green -> s11, blue -> stest).

[image]

The fact is, the solution does not climb asymptotically, but bounces back in periodic motion.
Also, the $s11$ solution related to NDSolveValue seems to "resist" less, and that is actually the solution I need for a later part of the work.
Of course I understand the numerical difficulties, but I would be very interested in learning how the computation can be pushed to the limits, how to get as close as possible to the exact asymptotic solution.

Needless to say, the difficulties are exacerbated as $\delta$ gets smaller, which does makes intuitively sense, see plot below for $\delta = 0.05$.

[image]

I tried using different solvers including "stiff" options, using very fine discretisations as in

```
Method -> {"MethodOfLines",
  "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MinPoints" -> 600, "MaxPoints" -> 600}},
```

playing with WorkingPrecision, AccuracyGoal, but have not achieved much.
Reading online I found a reference to rationalising all values, in order to allow the Working Precision setting to be effective, but I am not so sure on how to proceed with that, if the advice is correct at all.

Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**
I guess an accurate computation of the turning points is an absolute pre-requisite, but when I try something on the lines of

```
        max = First@
          NMaximize[{-U[x], 0 <= x < 0.5 }, {x}, Method -> "NelderMead", 
         WorkingPrecision -> 50, AccuracyGoal -> 50]
```

I get the warning message

```
   NMaximize::precw: The precision of the argument function (-1+x-4 
   (1.*10^-24/(0.0112246 +x)^12-1.*10^-12/(0.0112246 +x)^6)) is less than 
   WorkingPrecision (50).
```

Comment: What actually do you try to solve? Do you need numerical solution at $\delta \rightarrow 0$ or you try to compare different numerical method?

Comment: I need a numerical solution ideally via NDSolveValues for as small as possible $\delta$. As written, I have an analytical.solution for the limit $\delta \to 0$, but it is not smooth and I need a numerical approximation for further computations.

Comment: Smerdjakov, since you need infinite time to get to hyperbolic point, infinite accuracy seems to be required as you move closer to it. I've tested projection + symplectic integration method for NDSolve with hamiltonian as invariant for your problem, incresing precision ( and decreazing integration time step) provides diminishing return as expected

Comment: Since 2d is integrable, you can also get formal (implicit) solution as integral then you can use NIntegrate and FindRoot with required precision

Comment: @I.M, thanks for this. I understand I cannot get the exact solution, I am though interested in getting as good an approximation as reasonably feasible. The solutions I compute now seem very poor, with the particles bouncing back from the top very quickly, says a couple of seconds (as per plots). Between infinite time and 2 seconds, there must be something better! I would love to see the solutions you are able to get with your method, which sounds very interesting.

Comment: @I.M, your second comment makes actually very much sense, thanks a lot

Comment: Also, you step solution is not part of separatrix (no hyperbolic points at delta equal to zero, no separatrix as a consequence).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The precision of Mathematica numbers can be defined automatically. In this case number 1/2 is exact, while 0.5 has machine precision. If we evaluate `$MachinePrecision` then we get 15.9546. It is less then 50 we are state with option `WorkingPrecision->50`. Therefore system send a message about it. To solve the problem we define

```
J1[delta_, 
  w_] := (4*((delta/(w + 2^(1/6)*delta))^12 - (delta/(w + 
            2^(1/6)*delta))^6) + 1) - w; U[x_] := J1[1/2, x]

max = First@
  NMaximize[{-U[x], 0 <= x < 1/2}, {x}, Method -> "NelderMead", 
   WorkingPrecision -> 50, AccuracyGoal -> 50]
```

Finally we have answer

```
0.0023185928058613901272866241611963493788465890656335
```

The potential `-U[x]` has very sharp form around `max` point at $\delta \rightarrow 0$, we plot it as follows

```
Plot[Evaluate[Table[-J1[d, x], {d, {1, 0.5, .1, .01}}]], {x, -.2, .2},
  PlotRange -> {-1, .1}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"y", "U"}, 
 PlotLegends -> {1, 0.5, .1, .01}]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Hence, there is no chance to put something on the top of the hill, since it is not stable. The best what we can with standard numerical method it is approach this point and stay on it but not so long. For this we define module

```
ysol[d_] := 
 Module[{del = d}, 
  J1[delta_, 
    w_] := (4*((delta/(w + 2^(1/6)*delta))^12 - (delta/(w + 
              2^(1/6)*delta))^6) + 1) - w; U[w_] := J1[del, w];
  max = NMaximize[{-U[w], 0 <= w < 1/2}, {w}, Method -> "NelderMead", 
    WorkingPrecision -> 150, AccuracyGoal -> 150];
  turn = w /. 
    NSolve[{-U[w] == max[[1]], 1/2 <= w}, w, Reals, 
       WorkingPrecision -> 150][[1]][[1]]; L = 4; 
  stest = NDSolveValue[{y''[x] - U'[y[x]] == 0, y[0] == turn, 
     y'[0] == 0}, y, {x, 0, L}, WorkingPrecision -> 30, 
    MaxSteps -> Infinity]; 
  Plot[stest[x], {x, 0, 4}, PlotStyle -> Hue[d]]]
```

With this function we plot solution for $\delta =23/40, 1/3, 1/10, 1/100$ - blue, green, orange and red line consequently

```
Show[Table[ysol[d], {d, {23/40, 1/3, 1/10, 1/100}}]]
```

[image: Figure 2]

We can improve this result using very advanced method `"SymplecticPartitionedRungeKutta"` as follows

```
ysol[d_] := 
 Module[{del = d}, 
  J1[delta_, 
    w_] := (4*((delta/(w + 2^(1/6)*delta))^12 - (delta/(w + 
              2^(1/6)*delta))^6) + 1) - w; U[w_] := J1[del, w];
  max = NMaximize[{-U[w], 0 <= w < 1/2}, {w}, Method -> "NelderMead", 
    WorkingPrecision -> 150, AccuracyGoal -> 150];
  turn = w /. 
    NSolve[{-U[w] == max[[1]], 1/2 <= w}, w, Reals, 
       WorkingPrecision -> 150][[1]][[1]]; L = 4; 
  stest = NDSolveValue[{y''[x] - U'[y[x]] == 0, y[0] == turn, 
     y'[0] == 0}, y, {x, 0, L}, 
    Method -> {"SymplecticPartitionedRungeKutta", 
      "DifferenceOrder" -> 8, "PositionVariables" -> {y[x]}}, 
    StartingStepSize -> 1/1000, WorkingPrecision -> 30, 
    MaxSteps -> Infinity]; 
  Plot[stest[x], {x, 0, 4}, PlotStyle -> Hue[d]]]
```

With this function we plot 4 curves and see that all cases improved, but for $\delta =1/100$ we need to reduce  `StartingStepSize`.

```
Show[Table[ysol[d], {d, {1/2, 1/5, 1/10, 1/100}}]]
```

[image: Figure 3]
We also can try to apply some hand-made method, like very advanced rk4 method @Szabolcs

```
ClearAll[RK4step]
RK4step[f_, h_][{t_, y_}] := Module[{k1, k2, k3, k4}, k1 = f[t, y];
  k2 = f[t + h/2, y + h k1/2];
  k3 = f[t + h/2, y + h k2/2];
  k4 = f[t + h, y + h k3];
  {t + h, y + h/6*(k1 + 2 k2 + 2 k3 + k4)}]

ysol[nn_, d_] := 
 Module[{n = nn, delta = d}, 
  u = D[(4*((delta/(w + 2^(1/6)*delta))^12 - (delta/(w + 
               2^(1/6)*delta))^6) + 1) - w, w];
  f[t_, {x_, v_}] := {v, u /. {w -> x}}; 
  U[w_] := (4*((delta/(w + 2^(1/6)*delta))^12 - (delta/(w + 
              2^(1/6)*delta))^6) + 1) - w;
  max = NMaximize[{-U[w], 0 <= w < 1/2}, {w}, Method -> "NelderMead", 
    WorkingPrecision -> 250];
  turn = w /. 
    NSolve[{-U[w] == max[[1]], 1/2 <= w}, w, Reals, 
       WorkingPrecision -> 250][[1]][[1]]; 
  res = NestList[RK4step[f, 1/n], {0, {turn, 0}}, 4 n]; 
  ListPlot[Transpose[{res[[All, 1]], res[[All, 2, 1]]}], 
   PlotStyle -> Hue[delta], PlotRange -> {0, 1}, Frame -> True]]
```

It works well for moderate `delta`, for example

```
ysol[7 10^3, 23/40]
```

[image: Figure 4]

Update 1. To look closer at the point of reflection I have prepared this code

```
ysol1[d_] := 
 Module[{n = 10^3, delta = d}, 
  u = D[(4*((delta/(w + 2^(1/6)*delta))^12 - (delta/(w + 
               2^(1/6)*delta))^6) + 1) - w, w];
  U[w_] := (4*((delta/(w + 2^(1/6)*delta))^12 - (delta/(w + 
              2^(1/6)*delta))^6) + 1) - w;
  max = NMaximize[{-U[w], 0 <= w < 1/2}, {w}, Method -> "NelderMead", 
    WorkingPrecision -> 250];
  turn = w /. 
    NSolve[{-U[w] == max[[1]], 1/2 <= w}, w, Reals, 
       WorkingPrecision -> 250][[1]][[1]]; 
  Symplectic = {"SymplecticPartitionedRungeKutta", 
    "DifferenceOrder" -> 8, "PositionVariables" :> qvars}; 
  time = {x, 0, 4};
  qvars = {y[x]}; 
  eqs = {y''[x] - u == 0 /. w -> y[x], y[0] == Rationalize[turn], 
    y'[0] == 0}; 
  sol = NDSolveValue[eqs, {y[x], y'[x], y''[x]}, time, 
    Method -> Symplectic, StartingStepSize -> 1/n, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 60, MaxSteps -> Infinity, 
    MaxStepFraction -> delta^2]; sol]
```

Now we can check what happened with `y,y',y''` around the point of reflection, just evaluate and plot

```
With[{d = 1/10}, {ys, y1, y2} = ysol1[ d]; 


 tmin = t /. FindRoot[y1 /. x -> t, {t, 1.459}];
  LogPlot[
   Evaluate[{ys, Abs[y1], Abs[y2]} /. x -> t], {t, tmin - .05, 
    tmin + .05}, PlotLegends -> {"y", "y'", "y''"}, 
   PlotLabel -> Row[{"delta =", d}]]] // Quiet
```

Also same plot we did with `d=1/10`,  we plot for `d=1/100`, and get that in the point `y'=0` the second derivative `y''` equals to `2*10^-16` and `2*10^-14` for $d=1/10,1/100$ consequently. The question is why we did not stop integration?
[image: Figure 5]

Comment: thanks for this. I made the correction, but it does not solve the main problem: the orbit is still periodic. I made more attempts with the settings of NDSolve and NDSolveValue, but I hardly see any improvements. For example `s11 = NDSolveValue[{y''[x] - U'[y[x]] == 0, y[0] == turn[[1]], 
    y'[0] == 0}, y, {x, 0, L}, 
   Method -> {"BDF", "MaxDifferenceOrder" -> 1}, PrecisionGoal -> 20, 
   AccuracyGoal -> 20, WorkingPrecision -> 40, MaxSteps -> 10^6]; ` still gives the warning message that the maximum number of steps has been reached, and the solution shows no improvements.

Comment: @Smerdjakov What is `L` in your equations?

Comment: `L=10`, I forgot, it just a constant giving the domain over which the ODE solution is interesting

Comment: I am aware a solution might be to rescale the original variable to capture the "boundary layer" close to the top of the hill, but I am also interested in how accurate one can get with the brute force approach, if viable at all.

Comment: That is great help thanks a lot, veey instructive will read more about the method.

Comment: @Smerdjakov  Probably there is no conservative numerical scheme to approach equilibrium on the top of the hill. Thus we need to force event with `WhenEvent[]` or something like that.

Comment: I certainly understand getting asymptotically to the top of the hill is out of the question, I was just very interested in seeing what are the practical limits. Thanks again a lot

Answer (score 6):

OP is facing a problem that the numerical solution for a special orbit doesn't have the expected behavior. This special orbit is a part of the separatrix which is a collection of hyperbolic points (only one here) and their corresponding stable and unstable hyperbolic manifolds.

If we start at a turning point and move toward the hyperbolic point it should take infinite time (the hyperbolic point itself is not part of this orbit, but a separate orbit and we approach it asymptotically).

As I've mentioned in the comments since infinite time is required to (asymptotically) reach a hyperbolic point, intuitively, infinite precision is required as well. Since we perform numerical calculations, i.e. approximate, we should expect some kind of a problem as we are getting closer to h-point. And here due to round-off orbit jumps to the center manifold and becomes periodic (it could have jumped in the opposite direction too).

Similar to Alex, we can try to increase precision (the solution will still break at some point). With `NDSolve[]`, the key point is to use a symplectic integration method. Since the system is autonomous, the invariant (hamiltonian) is known and the projection method can be used too. Also, the integration step size and working precision are important.

```
Clear["Global`*"] ;
(* potential *)
ClearAll[potential] ;
potential[delta_][q_] := -((4*((delta/(q+2^(1/6)*delta))^12-(delta/(q+2^(1/6)*delta))^6)+1)-q)
(* hamiltonain *)
ClearAll[hamiltonian] ;
hamiltonian[delta_][q_,p_] := Evaluate[1/2*p^2+potential[delta][q]] ;
(* field *)
ClearAll[field] ;
field[delta_][q_,p_] := Evaluate[Dot[{{0,-1},{1,0}},D[hamiltonian[delta][q,p],{{q,p}}]]]
```

For a given potential we can compute critical and turning points:

```
(* compute and plot critical points *)
(* red   -- hyperbolic critical point *)
(* blue  -- elliptic critical point *)
(* green -- turnining point *)
delta = 1 ;
precision = 20 ;
points = {q, p} /. NSolve[field[delta][q,p] == 0 && q > 0, {q, p}, Reals, WorkingPrecision -> precision] // Transpose // First ;
critical = Plot[
    potential[delta][q],
    {q, 0, 1},
    PlotStyle -> Black, AspectRatio -> 1/2, ImageSize -> 400, Frame -> True, Axes -> False,
    Epilog -> {
        Gray, InfiniteLine[{First[points], potential[delta][First[points]]}, {1,0}],
        Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{First[points], potential[delta][First[points]]}],
        Blue, PointSize[Large], Point[{Last[points], potential[delta][Last[points]]}],
        Green, PointSize[Large], Point[{q /. Last[NSolve[potential[delta][q] == potential[delta][First[points]] && q > 0, WorkingPrecision -> precision]], potential[delta][First[points]]}]
    }
]
```

[image]

Usually, only the geometric shape of separatrix matters, it can be computed as a critical level of hamiltonian:

```
(* compute and plot separatrix as critical level set *)
limit = 200 ;
level = ContourPlot[
    Evaluate[hamiltonian[delta][q, p] == hamiltonian[delta][First[points], 0]],
    {q, 0, 1}, {p, -1, 1},
    PlotPoints -> limit, MaxRecursion -> 1, ContourStyle -> Black, AspectRatio -> 1/2, ImageSize -> 400
]
(* points can be extracted from plot *)
(* Cases[level, GraphicsComplex[list_,___] \[RuleDelayed] list, Infinity] *)
```

[image]

But since we want time history we can try direct integration or for 2d problem exact implicit solution also known.

Direct integration:

```
(* (direct integration) orbit from turning point to hyperbolic point, part of separatrix *)
ClearAll[orbit] ;
orbit[
    delta_,    (* -- parameter value *)
    limit_,    (* -- max integration time *)
    step_,     (* -- integration step size *)
    order_,    (* -- integration method difference order *)
    precision_ (* -- requested precision *)
] := Block[
    {qh, qe, qt, flow, initials, system, invariant, method, map, solution, range},
    (* critical points *)
    {qh, qe} = q /. NSolve[field[delta][q, p] == 0 && q > 0, {q, p}, Reals, WorkingPrecision -> precision] ;
    (* turning point *)
    qt = q /. NSolve[hamiltonian[delta][q, 0] == hamiltonian[delta][qh, 0] && q > qe, q,  Reals, WorkingPrecision -> precision] // First ;
    (* flow *)
    flow = Thread[Equal[{q'[t], p'[t]}, field[delta][q[t], p[t]]]] ;
    (* initials *)
    initials = {q[0] == Q, p[0] == P} ;
    (* system *)
    system = Join[flow, initials] ;
    (* invariant *)
    invariant = {hamiltonian[delta][q[t], p[t]]} ;
    (* integration method *)
    method = {"FixedStep", Method -> {"Projection", "Invariants" -> invariant, Method -> {"ImplicitRungeKutta", "DifferenceOrder" -> order, "Coefficients" -> "ImplicitRungeKuttaGaussCoefficients", "ImplicitSolver" -> {"Newton", AccuracyGoal -> precision, PrecisionGoal -> precision, "IterationSafetyFactor" -> 1}}}} ;   
    (* advance map *)
    map = ParametricNDSolveValue[system, q, {t, 0, limit}, {Q, P}, WorkingPrecision -> precision, MaxSteps -> Infinity, Method -> method, MaxStepSize -> step, StartingStepSize -> step] ;
    (* solution *)
    solution = map[qt,0] ;
    (* return orbit *)
    range = Range[0, limit, step] ;
    Transpose[N[{range, Map[solution, range]}]]
] ;
```

Test presicion:

```
(* test precision *)
delta = 1 ;
limit = 25 ;
step = 1/250 ;
order = 10 ;
precision = Range[15, 60, 15] ;
plot = ListPlot[
    ParallelMap[orbit[delta, limit, step, order, #] &, precision],
    PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Green, Magenta}, AspectRatio -> 1/2, ImageSize -> 400, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, PlotRange -> All,
    PlotLegends -> Map[StringTemplate["prec = ``"], precision]
]
```

[image]

As can be seen, the solution will eventually break and precision provides a diminishing return.

Implicit solution:

```
(* implicit solution *)
(* set parameter *)
delta = 1 ;
(* set precision *)
precision = 60 ;
(* compute critical points *)
{qh, qe} = q /. NSolve[field[delta][q, p] == 0 && q > 0, {q, p}, Reals, WorkingPrecision -> precision] ;
(* compute turning point *)
qt = q /. NSolve[hamiltonian[delta][qh, 0] == hamiltonian[delta][q, 0] && q > qe, q,  WorkingPrecision -> precision] // First ;
(* hamiltonian value *)
ht = hamiltonian[delta][qt, 0] ;
(* implicit solution *)
ClearAll[time] ;
time[q_?NumericQ] := Quiet[NIntegrate[-1/Sqrt[2*(ht-potential[delta][x])], {x, qt, q}, WorkingPrecision -> precision]] /; qh <= q <= qt ;
time[q_?NumericQ] := 0
(* numerical inverse *)
ClearAll[orbit] ;
orbit[t_] := q /. Quiet[FindRoot[t == time[q], {q, qh, qt}, Evaluated -> False, WorkingPrecision -> precision, MaxIterations -> 1000]] ;
```

Test implicit solution:

```
(* test implicit solution *)
range = Range[0, 10, 1/2] ;
data = {range, Map[orbit, range]} // N // Transpose ;
Show[plot,ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Black]]
```

[image]

The implicit solution should not break, but it becomes very expensive for large times. Also, warning messages are not shown in `NIntegrate[]` and `FindRoot[]`.

Both methods are not very practical. Since we are looking for a numerical (approximate) solution, we should embrace the fact that infinite precision is not an option.

A practical solution with controlled error can be done in the following way.
Select initial condition close to the hyperbolic point inside the center manifold. Perform integration in negative time up to a turning point (momenta flips sign). Replace the value of coordinate with a hyperbolic point for large times.

```
(* practical approximate solution *)
ClearAll[orbit] ;
orbit[
    delta_,    (* -- parameter value *)
    limit_,    (* -- max integration time *)
    step_,     (* -- integration step size *)
    epsilon_,  (* -- shift value *)
    order_,    (* -- integration method difference order *)
    precision_ (* -- requested precision *)
] := Block[
    {qh, qe, qt, flow, initials, system, invariant, method, map, point, count, result, time},
    (* critical points *)
    {qh, qe} = q /. NSolve[field[delta][q, p] == 0 && q > 0, {q, p}, Reals, WorkingPrecision -> precision] ;
    (* turning point *)
    qt = q /. NSolve[hamiltonian[delta][q, 0] == hamiltonian[delta][qh, 0] && q > qe, q,  Reals, WorkingPrecision -> precision] // First ;
    (* flow *)
    flow = Thread[Equal[{q'[t], p'[t]}, field[delta][q[t], p[t]]]] ;
    (* initials *)
    initials = {q[0] == Q, p[0] == P} ;
    (* system *)
    system = Join[flow, initials] ;
    (* invariant *)
    invariant = {hamiltonian[delta][q[t], p[t]]} ;
    (* integration method *)
    method = {"FixedStep", Method -> {"Projection", "Invariants" -> invariant, Method -> {"ImplicitRungeKutta", "DifferenceOrder" -> order, "Coefficients" -> "ImplicitRungeKuttaGaussCoefficients", "ImplicitSolver" -> {"Newton", AccuracyGoal -> precision, PrecisionGoal -> precision, "IterationSafetyFactor" -> 1}}}} ;   
    (* step advance map *)
    map = ParametricNDSolveValue[system, {q[-step], p[-step]}, {t, 0, -step}, {Q, P}, WorkingPrecision -> precision, MaxSteps -> Infinity, Method -> method, MaxStepSize -> step, StartingStepSize -> step] ;
    (* initial condition *)
    point = {qh + epsilon, 0} ;
    (* max number of iterations *)
    count = Floor[limit/step] ;
    (* main loop *)
    result = Most[NestWhileList[Apply[map], point, Composition[Curry[GreaterEqual][0], Last], 1, count]] ;
    (* max time *)
    time = Length[result]*step ;
    (* format result *)
    result = {Range[0, time-step, step], Reverse[First[Transpose[result]]]} // Transpose // N ;
    Piecewise[{{Interpolation[result][t], t < time},{qh, t >= time}}]
] ;
```

Test (see black curve, it is constant for large times by constraction):

```
delta = 1 ;
limit = 20 ;
step = 1/200 ;
epsilon = 10^-14 ;
order = 10 ;
precision = 20 ;
result = orbit[delta, limit, step, epsilon, order, precision] ;
Show[plot, Plot[result, {t, 0, 25}, PlotStyle -> Black, PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 200]]
```

[image]

It is also possible to find an approximate parametric representation of hyperbolic manifolds.
Some refs to start:

*M. N. Vrahatis, T. Bountis and M. Kollmann, ''Periodic Orbits and Invariant Surfaces in 4-D Nonlinear Mappings''
Stavros Anastassiou, Tassos Bountis and Arnd Backer, ''Homoclinic points of 2D and 4D maps via the parametrization method ''*

Here is an example of parameterization for a symplectic map in 2d. Note, since map is chaotic, stable and unstable manifold do not coincide but intersect infinitely many times. High res [pics](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1m2xUBeJvCawvz1e0YfGAXoAJlK8zubsq?usp=sharing).

[image]
[image]

Comment: It is very nice code (+1). But you have considered case `delta=1`, while the question is about minimal `delta`.

Comment: Thank you, that was very interesting. I also crudely implemented your advice from the comment, using Nintegrate on an expression obtained from the first integral, and it works great. I am experimenting with smaller deltas now, using the approaches you coded.

Comment: @AlexTrounev, there is no qualitative difference for 0 < delta < 1, the number of critical points is the same and etc. One just needs to select parameters carefully. My point was to illustrate the origin of numerical instability, show that increased accuracy doesn't solve the problem, and suggest a possible solution (exact implicit solution or part of the close periodic orbit).

Comment: @I.M.,  I am really grateful for the amount of work you put into this. It will take me a while to understand your coding. The methods are clear and very useful. I am mainly interested in the "very small" delta case, and I am getting results I do not understand using for example $\delta = 0.01$, I am trying to understand why, I am sure the methods would work. I got two very high quality answers and I have to choose one, I will have to go for the other one, as it solved specifically the problem I had. I am really grateful though, I am sorry I cannot choose yours, thanks again loads.